# Using attr in shape XML causes crash in Android

Tags: android, xml, attr

I have a drawable in this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
        android:gradientRadius="200dp"
        android:startColor="?attr/primaryDarkTransparent"
        android:type="radial" />
</shape>
```

The XML causes a crash when `startColor` uses `?attr/primaryDarkTransparent` saying:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: <internal><gradient> tag requires 'gradientRadius' attribute with radial type
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: <internal><gradient> tag requires 'gradientRadius' attribute with radial type`

The dramatic story is that it works very well when I use `attr` in `solid` and `stroke` but I don't know what the hell is going on in `gradient`.

Any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: android:type="radial" + attr only works for Android 10 but with a linear gradient it works at least until Android 5.0 API 21. Weird stuff!

Comment: Hi did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @MehranB A bit late but: As Benoit mentioned, appearently ?attr/ reference for raidal gradients are not supported below API 30 (Even though linear gradients support it). Only way i got it working, was using 2 seperated drawable files (For me it was an issue due to night/day theming). One file in /drawable using "day" colors and one file in /drawable-night using "night" colors, both referencing the specific color using: @color/

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your `shape`.

1. Below Android L (API 21) you can't use attributes in custom drawables, so you should replace `?attr/primaryDarkTransparent` with a `color` reference.
2. The `gradientRadius` should be a `float`. E.g. `200`

Comment: Note that your `color` resource can contain color attributes down to API 7 if you use `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList`.

Comment: It is possible to reproduce this issue on Android 9 (API 28), but ONLY if you are using radial gradients (Works fine for linear). :(
So seems like ?attr/ is supported above API 21, unless you are using radial gradients...

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** for a gradient from some color (could be solid or with some transparency) to the same color with any percentage of transparency.
***Note:*** *This is not a complete/general solution to the problem as the result will only have one color and it is applied to an ImageView (although it can be used in other types of Views).*
**Tested:** From API 31 down to 24.

**Steps:**
Create a shape with a gradient from some color with any percentage of transparency (black, for example, it doesn't matter which, it will be overridden later) into the same color with another percentage of transparency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="115%"
        android:centerX="1"
        android:centerY="1"
        android:startColor="#fe000000"
        android:centerColor="#f0000000"
        android:endColor="#50000000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image: rounded rectangle shape with transparency]

Then, in your **ImageView** add the following if you need it in the **foreground**:
This is the place where we use the **attr** from our **theme** to override the color we used in the gradient.

```
    android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_with_translucent_gradient"
    android:foregroundTint="?attr/colorSurface"
```

Or these for the **background**:

```
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_with_translucent_gradient"
    app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorSurface"
```

**Final result:**
Our ImageView over another ImageView and a TextView.

[image: Example of result]